# Whats the kohana function that takes text into uri

Tags: kohana

How can i generate a valid uri from a text string?

There should be a function/method in Kohana , which can do this?

Whats its called and how do i use it

Comment: Presumably you could just use rawurlencode()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[URL::title()](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/URL#title) combined with [URL::site()](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/URL#site) and [Route::url()](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Route#url) (in case you use routing)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be describing the [URL helper](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/URL). Specifically, look at the static [`title`](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/URL#title) and [`site`](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/URL#site) methods. Your question is just a little vague, but these sound to me to be close to what you're asking.